# Ag-grid grouping: setting groupRemoveSingleChildren only for one column

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Currently the `groupRemoveSingleChildren` property can only be set globally in the AGGrid.

How can I set this property to true only for one column ?

Example:

```
{
  field: 'section',
  rowGroup: true,
  hide: true,
  groupRemoveSingleChildren: true, // dosen't work, but you get the idea
},
{
  field: 'analyseLabel',
  rowGroup: true,
  hide: true,
  groupRemoveSingleChildren: false,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To whom may be interested, I received the answer from the AGgrid support.

You will find it here: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1565